# Angular template variables not resolved in PhpStorm

Tags: angular, phpstorm

I have an Angular 7 app in PhpStorm and resolution via ctrl click in templates works for everything (Angular specific attributes like *ngIf, custom component tags or pipes) but not for local variables.

For example I have this component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

Component({
    selector: 'test-component',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'
});
export class TestComponent {
    public list: string[];
}
```

With this template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of list">
    Hello {{x}}
</ng-container>
```

I can ctrl click on the imported module `@angular/core` to go to the definition, ctrl click on `*ngFor` to jump to the declarations file, click on `{{x}}` to jump to the *ngFor/let etc,. but I can NOT click on `list` to jump to the declaration in the .ts file. It's also rendered in red with the comment "unresolved variable or type".

I have node_modules installed, part of the project and not excluded. All Typescript and Angular autocomplete etc. works, except for template variables.

PhpStorm is 2019.2.3, the Angular plugin is installed and configured. I already have tried invalidate caches, re-index and re-start.

Comment: works fine for me using your (and similar) examples. If the issue persists after caches invalidation (*File > Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*), please create a support ticket, providing a sample project the issue can be reproduced with + idea.log

Comment: Thanks @lena, I figured it out in the meantime (see below).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the .html extension assigned to PHP (because I have many legacy files in the project). Curiously all Angular completion mechanics worked except for template variables. Assigning .html to Angular in the File Types area solved the problem.